# How to re-render a component from another component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to react and here is my question , is there's a way to re-render a component from another component?

I'm using Redux and some of the global state is effecting component B .
But in my example component B is not re-rendered after some Redux state is changing from component C .

component C and B are not father/child to each other ,
is there a simple way to do it?

thanks

Comment: You should include a minimal reproducible code sample

Comment: If a component doesn't re render when you changed the state that that component is selecting then you probably mutated the state in the reducer. To create a new state (you never actually change state but copy the parts of the state that need changed values) use the correct [immutable update patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

Answer (score 4):

Every component will re-render if any of the states connected to it change. So in order to cause a re-render, simply include that state in both components connect function.

Answer (score 2):

A frequent problem in Redux that causes this symptom is not using the spread operator to update the state object in your reducer. Try and return something like `{ ...state, newValue: 'food' }`

Comment: Please never do this, you will recreate the entire virtual DOM for no reason at all. It nullifies creating pure components and/or trying to memoize things.

Comment: hi @HMR, thanks for the response. Can you provide more detail on what this means? Would using the spread operator instead of deep clone be better?

Comment: In React you never change state by mutation. You always create a new state object but only re create the values that changed. For example: `{...state, changed:newValue}`. [Here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) are the immutable patterns you can use. If you were to deep clone then you'll re crate all values in state, even the ones that didn't change and cause all jsx to be re created, even the ones that would not need to change because the selectors would return a new object reference.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option on how to re-render component inside component in React 16.x using `Fragments`. Documentation on this can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

Short explanation: Your DOM will not be polluted with extra nodes, but will allow your app to use less memory which is always great. More in-depth explanation available [here](https://dev.to/tumee/react-fragments-what-why-how-2kh1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useNavigate` and navigate to the same url you are on. For example, as the last line of your function, you can say  `navigate("/...your current url....")`

`window.location.reload()` is not the best option everytime. It works on localhost, but for example on when you deploy it to the internet by using services such as "Netlify", it can can cause "not found url" error